# How to write value into an address in format string attack

Tags: c, string, security, format-string

I'm taking a security course which needs us to do format string attack on an unix virtual machine. The vulnerability is a format string using command line argument.

My question is how can I write value into an address in format string (like write shell code address into function return address)?

For example, I try to write value 987654 into the return address location 0xaabbccdd.
I tried some strings like `"AAAA_%10$x"`, and this can lead the program to print `AAAA_41414141`.

Then I replace the letters with my address and try to overwrite it.

```
\xdd\xcc\xbb\xaa_%10$x_%54321x_%n"
```

But it does not work. I see an article says I should use a smaller number in `%54321x` since there are some chars I already wrote, but I don't know how many chars I've written before `%54321x`, either.

note: The environment has an old version of gcc, so it's not necessary to worried about the value is too large.
Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`printf` cannot write anywhere without using the `%n` format specifier. This is the one you're missing. Something like `%.987654d%n` will write the number 987654 (the number of characters output so far) to an address specified by the second argument, where the first argument is an `int`. This should be enough to get you started.

Comment: `sprintf` writing to a char buffer on the stack could also be used to do malicious damage...

Comment: @Oli: yes but that's not a format string attack, which OP's assignment seems to be about...

Comment: I hardly call that a format string vuln, merely an ordinary `strcpy` buffer overflow. The fact that `sprintf` is being used instead of `strcpy` is rather incidental.

Answer (score 0):

you should specify wich offset of the stack to write in with the %n formatter like `%[offset]\$n`

example : `%23\$n`

be sure to correctly get the right address by cheking the result of \xdd\xcc`\xbb\xaa_%54321x_%[offset]\$x`" this can be done with python or bash script

you should retrieve the address **aabbccdd**